# Does the dihedral group $D_{12}$ have a subgroup of order $4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let the dihedral group $D_{12}=\{xy\mid x^6=y^2=1,xy=yx^{-1}=yx^5\}$

Order 2 subgroups are: $\{1, x^3\}$, $\{1, y\}$, $\{1, xy\}$, $\{1, x^2 y\}$,$\{1, x^3 y\}$, $\{1, x^4 y\}$,$\{1, x^5y\}$.

Order 3 subgroups are: $\{1, x, x^5\}$, $\{1, x^2, x^4\}$.

Order 6 subgroups are: $\{1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5\}$.

Does $D_{12}$ have a subgroup of order 4?

Comment: @DietrichBurde That question is about the subgroups of $D_4$.

Comment: @NormalHuman The question has beed answered several times at MSE. So it is definitely a duplicate. Perhaps a better link is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327191/is-there-a-general-formula-for-finding-all-subgroups-of-dihedral-groups.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $\{1,x^3,y,x^3y\}$, i.e. the group generated by a reflection and a rotation by 180 degrees.

Comment: (Which is a $2$-Sylow so it must exist, and all subgroups of order four have this form)

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen $\{1,x^3, y, x^3y\}$ is the unique subgroup of orden 4?

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero That is exactly what Pedro Tamaroff said.

Answer (score 0):

$D_{12} \cong S_3 \times C_2$. Hence $C_2 \times C_2$, the Klein $4$-group, is a subgroup of order $4$.