# how to list elements of a dihedral group $D_n$

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

A formula has been posted here ([Is there a general formula for finding all subgroups of dihedral groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327191/is-there-a-general-formula-for-finding-all-subgroups-of-dihedral-groups)). However, I'm unfamiliar of the notation used. With the rule stated on the link, how do I list the elements of a given dihedral group $D_n$. An example would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: They're $e, s, r, rs, r^2, r^2s, r^3, r^3s, ..., r^{n-1}, r^{n-1}s$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

(Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group)
The group presentation of a dihedral group $D_n$ is
$$\langle r,s:r^n=1,s^2=1,sr=r^{-1}s\rangle$$
Since $D_n$ is generated by $r$ and $s$, every element will be of the form
$$r^{\alpha_1}s^{\beta_1}\dots r^{\alpha_k}s^{\beta_k}$$
where $0\leq\alpha_i<n, 0\leq\beta_i<2$ and $k\geq 1$.
Since we can always swap the position of $s$ and $r$ by using the relation $sr=r^{-1}s$, we can always write the element in the form
$$r^\alpha s^\beta$$
where $0\leq\alpha_i<n, 0\leq\beta_i<2$.

Hence $D_n$ consists of $1,r,r^2,\dots,r^{n-1},s,rs,\dots,r^{n-1}s$. But to complete the proof, you still have to show that all the elements in the list are distinct. This will be left as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a rotation through $2π/n$, call it $\rho$.  And a reflection $\sigma$.  You can get all the other rotations as powers of $\rho$.  And the other reflections by application of $\rho$ successively to $\sigma$.  That's a reflection followed by a rotation is another reflection.

So we get $D_{2n}=\{e,\rho,\rho^2,\dots,\rho^{n-1},\sigma,\rho\sigma,\dots,\rho^{n-1}\sigma\}$.